# Unable to locate publishable resources when trying to publish a Laravel Package

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php

My Directory set-up looks like this:

```
|- packages
|-|-- Iezon
|---|-- Core
      |-- Admin
        |-- src
        |--|-- database
        |-----|-- migrations
        |--------|-- xxxx_xx_xx_xxxxxx_create_admin_panels.php
        |--|-- Http
        |----|-- routes.php
        |--|-- Providers
        |-----|-- AdminServiceProvider.php
        |--|-- Resources
        |-----|-- views
```

My `AdminServiceProvider.php` looks like this:

```
namespace Iezon\Core\Admin\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AdminServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../Http/routes.php');
        $this->loadViewsFrom (__DIR__ . '/../Resources/views', 'admin');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations', database_path('migrations')]);
    }

    protected function loadRoutesFrom(string $path)
    {
        require_once $path;
    }
}
```

My `composer.json` looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        ...
        "Iezon\\Core\\Admin\\": "packages/Iezon/Core/Admin/src",
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run `composer dumpautoload` and then try to run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Iezon\Core\Admin\Providers\AdminServiceProvider"
```

I get this:

> Unable to locate publishable resources.

I then check it exists with `php artisan vendor:publish` and it does not show in the list of Providers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->publishes(...)` actually belongs inside the `boot` method, not in `register`. Also, you need to pass an associative array, but instead you pass two individual values. Finally, it is a best practice to only call `publishes` when the provider is actually running in console like this:

```php
if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
       $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations' => database_path('migrations')]);
}
```